# CSS Zebra stripping not working properly

Tags: html, css

I am trying to have Zebra stripping for my table but it is not working properly.

```
<style>
tr.campaign:nth-of-type(even)
{
    background:#e0e0e0;
}

tr.campaign:nth-of-type(odd)
{
    background:#f1f1f1;
}

</style>
<table>
<tr class="campaign">
    <td rowspan="2">hey</td>
    <td>row 1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>row 2</td>
</tr>

<tr class="campaign">
    <td rowspan="2">hey</td>
    <td>row 3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>row 4</td>
</tr>

</table>
```

I am trying with above code. Actually rows with campaign class should be colored in zebra strips but it is considering other rows too for coloring. Thus, second row with campaign class is colored with same color as that of 1row with campaign class due to 2 rows above second campaign class.

Regards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no way to do this in Selectors level 3. `:nth-of-type` will always take all `tr` siblings into account, not only those that are matched:

> The `:nth-of-type(an+b)` pseudo-class notation represents an element that has `an+b-1` siblings with the same expanded element name before it in the document tree, for any zero or positive integer value of `n`, and has a parent element.

In Selectors level 4 (which is currently not implemented in any browser) there will be `:nth-match`:

> `:nth-match(an+b of selector-list)` pseudo-class notation represents an element that has a parent and has `an+b-1` siblings that match the given selector-list before it in the document tree, for any zero or positive integer value of `n`.

Resources:

- W3C: Selectors Level 3: [`:nth-of-type`](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#nth-of-type-pseudo)
- W3C: Selectors Level 4: [`:nth-match`](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/#nth-match)