# CSS - Using adjacent selectors in combination with nth-of-type

Tags: css, css-selectors

What I'm trying to do is select every fourth DIV following a heading tag. Here's a basic idea of the code I'm using.

```
<div class="view-content"> 

   <h3>The Heading</h3> 
   <div></div>  
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div>Trying to select this DIV</div>

   <h3>The Heading</h3> 
   <div></div>  
   <div></div>
   <div></div>

   <h3>The Heading</h3> 
   <div></div>  
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div>Trying to select this DIV</div>  
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div>Trying to select this DIV</div>

</div><!-- .view-content -->
```

I'm using Drupal, so I'm limited to writing CSS to arrange the content. The reason I'm trying to select every fourth DIV is because there are four DIVs to a row and I want to remove the right margin from the fourth (and last) DIV of a row. Some rows only have one or two DIVs and others have ten or more.

The CSS that I originally wrote (that doesn't seem to work) is:

```
div.view-content h3 + div:nth-of-type(4n) {
margin-right: 0px;
}
```

Maybe I'm overthinking this, or maybe there's no way to do it. Either way, please help!

Comment: Can't just throw a class onto the elements you want to select? (I'm not familiar with Drupal)

Comment: Unfortunately in this case Drupal can only apply the same class to all the elements or none at all.

Comment: `h3 + div:nth-of-type(4n)` means "match this `div` if it's the 4nth of its type and it directly follows an `h3`." which is why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, it appears [there's no nice, general way to do this with CSS3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9988264/139010). Taking some inspiration from the other answer posted here, you can pull it off for a limited number of elements:

```
div.view-content h3 + div+div+div+div,
div.view-content h3 + div+div+div+div + div+div+div+div,
div.view-content h3 + div+div+div+div + div+div+div+div + div+div+div+div /*etc*/ {
    margin-right: 0px;
}
```

http://cssdesk.com/Ty7Gf

Comment: For anybody looking at that other answer, don't bother holding your breath - `:nth-match()` as it is currently proposed won't help here either.

Comment: Actually, the linked post doesn't seem very relevant. That post is about attempting using `:nth-of-type()` like `:nth-match()` (wrongly), whereas the question here is asking how to give `:nth-of-type()` a specific point to start counting from. That said, the common issue here is that `:nth-of-type()` always counts based on all siblings under the same parent as a whole, not from any point or with any filtering.

Comment: Setting yours as the answer, because as you said, there doesn't seem to be any way to do this nicely with CSS3.

Answer (score 0):

`h3 + div + div + div + div{background-color:red;}`

or to match yours:

```
div.view-content h3 + div + div + div + div {
   margin-right: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. I actually just edited the example as you answered. How can I select every fourth, rather than just the fourth immediately following the header?

Comment: Actually I don't think that's possible cross-browser only with css, unless you know there will be max 20-elements, you can just extend it `h3 + div + div + div + div + div + div + div + div` for 8, and so on, not nice but cross-browser, only other option I believe is js

Comment: Hmm, I guess it's back to the drawing board.